Created MS Teams App in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.11.5 but is not able to deploy/publish it
I'm trying to create a MS Teams App for my company.
I created a MS Teams App in Visual Studio 2022, ver 17.11.5.
The Solution structure is like this:
Solution
If I run the application from Visual Studio, it works fine. But whenever I try to publish/deploy it in for my Organization, it only displays the opening screen and logo. It doesn't display the contents of the Tab App.
I tried to publish the APP in IIS (it is publicly available, HTTPS) and then tried to pointing the URL in manifest.json file, but nothing worked.
Any tips/suggestions would surely help.
Thanks

Hello @Tridib - Could you please check error logs via opening DevTools F12 in Browser and share the error log details?

@ChetanSharma-msft - browser console error : The server responded with a status of 404 : tab

Could you please follow the document for deployment-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?tabs=net80&pivots=development-environment-vs&toc=%2Fvisualstudio%2Fazure%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fvisualstudio%2Fazure%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json#publish-your-web-app
2.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/?view=vs-2022

The issue got resolved after Provision in Cloud, with Azure subscription.
Provision
The next step is Deploy to the Cloud.
